# Can't adjust the volume in my iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, volume

I have a very weird problem. The volume button can only adjust the ringtone volume instead of volume  inside my application. There must be a way to control it. Because I found some apps can adjust ringtone volume and some apps can adjust volume.

In another word how to category my app as an "music" app so that I can adjust eh playback volume instead of the ringtone volume when I press the hardware volume key.

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: Goto -> Setting -> Sounds -> Change with Button -> YES

Comment: I don't think you get what I mean. I want to control this in my program. My question actually is why I can adjust ringtone for some apps and can adjust playback volumes for others.There must a why to control it in my program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code will allow user to adjust the volume of play instead of ring tone.

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```